# Finding a polynomial of minimum degree given series

Tags: algorithm, math, series

Given a series on number, how can be find a polynomial which generalizes the series. And than with this generalization one should be able to find out any term in the series.

While searching on net I found out that one can use Langrange's Interpolation technique. How accurate is the method for generalizing the series?

Can we use some other method to find a polynomial?

Comment: What do you mean by 'how accurate'?

Comment: Does it interpolates the curve exactly or approximates it?

Comment: There's no way to get polynomial in exact form for common case (if count of numbers in series can be anything). You may try to implement [interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation) - but still it's not native "polynomial" solution

Comment: I think for this case it's possible to get exact polynomial. The simplest one just take the polynomial with the same degree as the number of data points. Since we need the minimum degree, then we try to reduce the degree. This reduction process is what being questioned by OP, whether it's exact reduction (i.e., still match the series exactly), or approximation.

Comment: And btw, [Lagrange's Interpolation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInterpolatingPolynomial.html) polynomial is exact. Another simple exact method can be [Neville's algorithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NevillesAlgorithm.html)

Comment: @justhalf Thanks, Neville's seems simpler than lagrange's interpolation

Answer (score 1):

There are several algorithms which will generate a polynomial matching a finite series, as "justhalf" identified Lagrange's interpolation is one technique.

In general, if you are given a function with n points, you can uniquely define a polynomial of degree n-1 (or sometimes less) which matches at every point.

Consider the series with only two term, "2, 4". As this has only two terms (n=2), there is a polynomial of degree 1 which will generate the series. The general form is y = ax+b and we need to find a and b:

y = ax + b

So

> 2 = a⋅1 + b      =>      2 =   a + b
>   4 = a⋅2 + b      =>      4 = 2a + b

Therefore a = 2 and b = 0.

y = 2x

You can see if you substitute x=1 and x=2 you get the values 2 and 4 respectively.

If the series was 2,4,8 then you would need a polynomial of degree 3-1 = 2, say y = ax^2 + bx + c (where these a and b are new values, not necessarily the same as the a and b for the previous case).

Then you would know that:

> 2 = a⋅1² + b⋅1 + c      =>      2 =   a +   b + c      (i)
>   4 = a⋅2² + b⋅2 + c      =>      4 = 4a + 2b + c       (ii)
>   8 = a⋅3² + b⋅3 + c      =>      8 = 9a + 3b + c       (iii)

You can solve these equations to find a, b and c:

Subtract (i) from (ii):

> 2 = 3a + b         (iv)

Subtract (ii) from (iii)

> 4 = 5a + b        (v)

Subtract (iv) from (v)

> 2 = 2a      =>      a = 1

So from (iv)

> 2 = 3⋅1 + b = 3 + b      =>      b = -1

From (i)

> 2 = a + b + c = 1 + -1 + c = c      =>       c = 2

So the polynomial y = ax² + bx + c = x² - x + 2 agrees at the three points

Verify:

> 1² - 1 + 2 = 2
>   2² - 2 + 2 = 4
>   3² - 3 + 2 = 8

As we wanted.

But note that this polynomial y = x² - x + 2 also exactly generates the series with only the first 2 terms, "2, 4". So this series with only two terms is satisfied by two polynomials, y = 2x and y = x² - x + 2. Despite agreeing on the first two values 2,4 these are very different polynomials.

In general, if you have a series of n terms then there is a unique polynomial of degree n-1 which will generate the series. In general, there will be no polynomials of degree less than n-1 which will exactly generate it (you may get lucky, but its not generally true). There are an infinite number of polynomials of degree greater then n-1 which will generate the data.

Usually in numerical analysis you try and generate a polynomial of degree less than n-1 which approximates the data (doesn't match exactly, but minimises error). Exact solutions of degree n-1 are unstable, in that tiny changes to the input series produces very different equations. This is not so true of polynomial approximations of degree less than n-1. As many physical measurements have inherent error, using lower degree polynomials minimises the impact of measurement errors.

Lets now consider the series 2, 4, 8, 16

You can produce a polynomial of degree 3 (y = ax³ + bx² + cx + d) which exactly matches these data points using exactly the same approach. This (again) is just solving a set of linear simultaneous equations. This is essentially how Lagrange's algorithm works; we have solved the equations by hand instead of using matrix notation (as Lagrange does).

But given 2,4,8,16 most people would think that the equation is y = 2<sup>x</sup>. This is not a polynomial equation, so can't be expressed as a polynomial.

For the series 2,4,8 we derived the polynomial y = x² - x + 2. If we tried to extrapolate to find the next value, plugging x=4 will give us y = 4² - 4 + 2 = 14. The term after (x=5) that would be y = 5² - 5 + 2 = 22. As x gets larger, y = x² - x + 2 becomes an increasingly bad approximation to y = 2<sup>x</sup>. In fact no polynomial will grow as fast as y = 2<sup>x</sup>.

So ...

If you have n points, you can always find a unique polynomial of degree n-1 (or sometimes less) which will generate exactly those n points for x=1,2,3..n. This is not often used for real life problems, because these solutions are unstable (small changes to input produce large changes to the polynomial).

If you have n points, there are an infinite number of polynomials of degree n or greater which will produce the series. These all have identical values for x = 1, 2, ... n but will disagree on the n+1, n+2 etc terms.

Typically a polynomial approximation of degree less than n-1 is used. It won't usually be an exact fit, but will often show the general shape of the curve. For 8 points you might try and find a polynomial of degree 4 (y = ax⁴ + cx³ + dx² + e) which minimises the error. As a rule of thumb, a polynomial of degree of about n/2 is often used. This is more art than science; usually you have some idea of what the underlying (correct) formula is, and this helps select the degree of the approximating polynomial.

Polynomial approximations can work reasonably well for interpolation (finding a value between two data points) but are hopeless for extrapolation. As we have no knowledge at all of what the "next" value is a series might be (it could be anything), no formula can successfully predict it.

I hope this is useful. Producing a polynomial which exactly generates a finite series is not hard ... its simply solving n linear simultaneous equations with n variables (the coefficients of x<sup>n-1</sup>, x<sup>n-2</sup>, ... x², x, and the constant term). This is what we have done above and how Lagrange works. However, in physical systems it may not be particularly meaningful. User beware.